# Kite autocomplete is not giving me free suggestions - only 30 per day - no pro suggestions

Tags: python-3.x, kite

I installed the Kite autocomplete for Python (Anaconda-Spyder is my main IDE , though I also use SublimeText)
And i get this pic:
[Kite Pro ripping me off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBLHe.png)
(Even when I do not get any starred autocompletions of any sort ...)
Isn't it supposed to say 3 starred completions left today??

Even when i sign out and back in , uninstall Kite, clear my registry and remove temp and program files, i notice it *somehow* knows that I have used up some of its 30 completions and gives me only 30 per day
Even if I sign out of Kite (no way for it to know I have an account with a Pro free trial , right?? ),I still get only 30 completions per day, and after that kite is "locked" - null completions today ...
And i don't even get the Starred completions - the Pro completions
So is it a mistake on my installation ? Will adding Kite to my PATH help?? (I seriously doubt it )
Or is it a bug on the devs' side ??

Any help regarding this matter would be appreciated ...
I simply cannot stand the fact that my bro gets FREE autocompletions per day, and that too unlimited ones at that ( which I guess is the free tier of Kite , since he gets only 3 starred ones)

Answer (score -1):

I think there might be a bug on Kite's side.
However, I do not face the problem mentioned above :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/259T8.png |
I receive unlimited free tier auto-completions and only 3 *Pro* completions.Hope this answer helps you!